# Automatic Lookup Across Tables in AppSheet

Tags: google-appsheet

Hi I'm having a problem with looking up data on another table with AppSheet
Basically, when I scan in a barcode, I want the product name to lookup such that in SQL

```
SELECT productName
FROM productLookupTable
WHERE productLookupTable.barcode == the_scanned_barcode
```

However, I can't seem to do this in appsheet. I tried

```
LOOKUP([barcode],'productLookupTable','barcode','productName')
```

as the formula for the product name field in the add view and that didn't work either. Scanning a barcode didn't trigger a lookup, or it says match not found. (Two different scenarios of many combinations of things I tried.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost there. I had to use

```
LOOKUP([_Thisrow].[barcode],'productLookupTable','barcode','productName')
```

the key part is

```
[_Thisrow]
```

Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use double quote insted of single quote?

LOOKUP([barcode],"productLookupTable","barcode","productName")

I think you should change the type of [barcode] and [barcode] from productLookupTable table to Text.